# Wifi not working on Odin - Dell 9343 XPS13

Tags: wifi, drivers, release-odin, dell

i tried installing odin on my Dell XPS13 9343 (2015 model), but could not manage to get wifi working. After installation, I installed bcmw-kernel-source from USB stick, but still no wifi available. When I try this command:

> lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

I get this output:

> 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
> BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
> Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
> Kernel modules: bcma

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

solved! found the solution over here:

> https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/1603#issue-965454894

Comment: This hint really helped, thanks!